# Select columns dynamically from Datatable C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net

I have a `Datatable` like below

| column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 10 | 20 | 3 |
| 35 | 45 | 5 | 10 |
| 11 | 10 | 30 | 5 |
| 30 | 13 | 15 | 1 |

The datatable has around 30 columns. sample I have mentioned 4 columns(like above)

```
var groupbyColumns=list<string>(){"column1","column2"};

var aggregateColumns=List<string>(){"Column3"};
```

Note: columns will be dynamically change based on user selection from UI.

Expected Result:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 10 | 50 |
| 35 | 45 | 5 |
| 30 | 13 | 15 |

I have to group by based on `groupbyColumns` list and then sum columns based on `aggregateColumn` list.

For example, if `groupbyColumns` contains 2 columns and `aggregateColumn` contains 2 columns means result has to be 4 columns.

Someone please help me to achieve this?

Comment: Stating requirements is not the same as asking a question. What have you tried, and what is not working?

Comment: Easiest solution is https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Comment: I tried with Dynamic.core but couldn't achieve. Group by could not able to do with dynamic columns.

Comment: Could you please update your question with valid C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `IEqualityComparer` for `IEnumerable` that provides sequence equality, you can generate a key that is usable with `GroupBy`. I use an static method to make creating it a little simpler.

```
public static class Make {
    public static IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> IESequenceEqual<T>() => new IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T>();
    public static IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> IESequenceEqual<T>(T _) => new IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T>();

    private class IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
        public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) =>
            Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x != null && y != null && (x.SequenceEqual(y)));

        public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> items) {
            // Will not throw an OverflowException
            //unchecked {
            //    return items.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(17, (a, b) => 23 * a + b);
            //}
            var hc = new HashCode();
            foreach (var item in items)
                hc.Add(item);
            return hc.ToHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Since you seemed to specify the answer should be a `DataTable`, you need an extension method to convert the result into one. I use `IDictionary<string,object>` as an intermediary to pass column names and values when generated dynamically.

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> rows) {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        if (rows.Any()) {
            foreach (var kv in rows.First().OrderBy(e => e.Key))
                dt.Columns.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value.GetType());

            foreach (var r in rows)
                dt.Rows.Add(r.Values.Select(v => (object)v).ToArray());
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Now you just group by your `groupByColumns`, sum your `aggregateColumns` and convert the result to a `DataTable`. I use `ValueTuple` to represent each column name, value pair to convert into the `Dictionary`.

```
var groupByColumns = new[] { "Column1", "Column2" }.ToList();
var aggregateColumns = new[] { "Column3" }.ToList();

var ans = src.AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(r => groupByColumns.Select(c => r[c]), Make.IESequenceEqual<object>())
             .Select(rg => groupByColumns.Zip(rg.Key, (c,v) => (c, v))
                                         .Concat(aggregateColumns.Select(c => (c, v:(object)rg.Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r[c])))))
                                         .ToDictionary(ck => ck.c, ck => ck.v))
             .ToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working as expected.